Ларавел. Подставить в результаты запроса значения по умолчанию, описанные в модели
Есть модель Azbuka. В ней есть колонка 'settings' типа JSON (Postgre).
В модели прописаны значения по умолчанию:
    protected $casts = [
        'settings' => 'array',
    ];

    protected $attributes = [
       'settings' => '{
           "enabled": null,
           "type": null,
           "timer": 0,
       }',
   ];

В БД есть несколько записей, в части которых ранее не были добавлены эти параметры (type, timer). Каким образом можно через Azbuka::all() получить эти значения по умолчанию "в ответе"?

Может проще реализовать акcессор? При наличии установленного атрибута - его возвращать, а при отсутствии - генерировать атрибут поумолчанию.

Можете создать простую команду которая возмет всех у кого нет атрибута, и обновит их.
